# save a file modified using a list (c language)

Tags: c, list, file, memory, complexity-theory

=============================================================
edit : im sorry it seems like i havent explained well
what my program does is
`open file for reading` **=>** `load list from the file` **=>** `operations chosen by user will be applies to list (not file)`(add-search-display-reset)\ **=>** `import change to file`(in case there is any)
if the user chooses to only add an employee and quit `will it be better` to append the added node to the end of file, close and free list `or` its okay to open file for reading and overwrite all the nodes from the beggining
this last option will save me a lot of lines of code but will it save time and energy for the user while execution ?

=============================================================

i am workig on a (c language) school project where we have to use both `lists` and `files` to :

- display a list of employees
- add employees
- search an employee
- reset list
- save and quit

so i am looking for the best way to do it, and as i know a good code is the one that ensures the program uses as `less memory` as it can and be as `fast` as it can.
what i am asking you is
after opening the file that contains the infos of employees and loadig it to the list, and modifying the list by `add` or `reset`, would it be better to :

- open the file for "w" and fill it with the list.
- or open it for "a+" to add from last employee.

note that this last way i will have to memorize the initial_number_of_lines (aka nodes) and look for the 'initial last node' to start loading from it.
note : the **employee** variables are `first_name` `last_name` and `salary`; VERIFY(file) returns 1 i file opened returns 0 if not;

```
void load_file(list *list, char *filename)
{
    if (current_number_of_lines != initial_number_of_lines || list_reset == 1)
    {
        if (current_number_of_lines > initial_number_of_lines && list_reset == 0)
        {
            FILE *file = fopen(filename, "a+");
            if (VERIFY(file) == 1)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < initial_number_of_lines; i++)
                {
                    list = list->next;
                }
                while (list != NULL)
                {
                    fprintf(file, "%s\t%s\t%lf\n", list->emp.Fname, list->emp.Lname, list->emp.salary);
                    list = list->next;
                }
            }
            fclose(file);
        }
        else if (list_reset == 1)
        {
            FILE *file = fopen(filename, "w");
            while (list != NULL)
            {
                fprintf(file, "%s\t%s\t%lf\n", list->emp.Fname, list->emp.Lname, list->emp.salary);
                list = list->next;
            }
            fclose(file);
        }
        else
            printf("Error\n");
    }
    freeList(list);
}
```

Comment: If you delete elements, you must rewrite the file.

Comment: To me it's strange that the function name is **load**_file when it seems the code **writes** the file.

Comment: Edited my answer to give hints according to your change in your question. Please read my answer again.

Answer (score 0):

If you use "w" to fopen() then it will truncate file to zero length or create text file for writing.  The stream is positioned at the beginning of the file. You have to write all records to the file.

If you use "a+" to fopen() then the file will be open for reading and appending (writing at end of file). The file is created if it does not exist.  Output is              always appended to the end of the file. Warning: POSIX is silent on what the initial read position is when using this mode. In the mode, you will only write records that needs to be added.

Please also note that neither of the methods are well suited for sharing the data between two or more applications.

If new records are added at the end of the list, obviously it is faster to append those records ate the end of the file ("a+" mode).

Since you have a text file (made of text lines), it is unfortunately not possible to update the changed records. In that case, you must write everything from the list to the file ("w" mode).

If you change you file format in order to use a fixed size record then you can optimize the writing by positioning the file on the record and then write. For that, you'll define your record as a struct containing fixed size strings. And of course add an item in that struct to remember where it has been read from the list.

Answer (score 0):

If all your `add` operations adds the new node to the end of the list, you will get better performance using `a+`. On the other hand, the code will be more simple if you always rewrite the the whole file. So what is most important for you? Performance or simple code? I would start with the simple approach.

Some other notes.

It's pretty strange that you call the function **load**_file when it actually writes the file.

The variables: `current_number_of_lines`, `initial_number_of_lines`, `list_reset` seem to be **global** variables. Using global variables is something you should avoid.

The logic (aka `if` statements) seems too complicated. You can simply do:

```
void load_file(list *list, char *filename)
{
    if (list_reset == 1)
    {
        ...
    }
    else if (current_number_of_lines > initial_number_of_lines)
    {
        ...
    }
    else if (current_number_of_lines < initial_number_of_lines)
    {
        printf("Error\n");
    }
    freeList(list);
}
```